# How to create qf or location list from results of shell command

Tags: external-command, quickfix, vimgrep, location-list

I often open the results of an external project-wide `find | xargs grep` command into a new tab like this `:tabnew|read !find . -iname \*.py | xargs grep -n 'pattern'`

I then use `gf` to open the matching files and perform edits.  While this is handy, the file opens with the cursor on the top-most line of the file.

I want to be able to jump directly to the exact line as indicated by the results (note the use of `grep -n` to include line numbers in the results).

Is it possible to "promote" or "convert" the results of the command to a quickfix or location list?

Or, conversely, is there a command other than `gf` that will jump to not only the file but the exact line in the file as indicated by the results?

[Edit: I know of `:vimgrep /pattern/ **/*.py` but I don't know how to tell it not to follow symlinks (whereas `find` won't follow links unless `-L` is specified).  There's also the problem of `**` exhausting the command buffer if there are too many files... hence why I use `find | xargs grep`.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `gF` command is jumping at a specific line within the file.

It open the file at the number specified *after* the file name where the file name and the line number are separated by a non `isfname` character.

Your grep result need to be adapted accordingly.

Comment: ah... so simple!  thank you :)  [btw, the filepath:line notation seems to be supported just fine out of the box]

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question more directly, you can use `:help :cexpr` or `:help :cgetexpr` in combination with `:help system()` to populate the quickfix:

```
:cexpr system("find . -iname \*.py | xargs grep -n 'pattern'")
```

Once the quickfix is populated, you can use `:help :cn`, `:help :cp`, `:help :cc`, etc. to move around and/or open the quickfix window with `:help :cwindow`:

[image: qf]

Comment: that's awesome!  even better than using tabnew|read + gF because I don't have to move the cursor over the file name at the beginning of a line in the results list.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple Neovim/Lua example, for inspiration:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_user_command('TorgleFlidgets',
    function()
        vim.cmd.cclose()
        print(' torgling the flidgets ...')
        local out = vim.fn.systemlist("torgle ./flidgets.txt")
        if vim.v.shell_error == 0 then
            print('nothing to see here')
            return
        end
        local files = {}
        for _, file in pairs(out) do
            local parts = {}
            for part in string.gmatch(file, "%S+") do
                table.insert(parts, part)
            end
            table.insert(files, {filename = parts[1], lnum = parts[2], col = parts[3]})
        end
        vim.fn.setqflist(files)
        vim.cmd.copen()
    end,
    {nargs = 0}
)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved if it explained how this function addresses the question.